# Can't use fabric put - Is there any server configuration needed?

Tags: python, ubuntu, fabric

I'm using `fabric` to do a remote deployment of my app on a rackspace server. I've tried my scripts on virtual machines using the same OS (Ubuntu Server 10.04) on my home computer and they all seem to work.

Strangely, all `put` fabric commands fail on the real server. All other commands (`run`, `cd`, `sudo`, etc) seem to work ok.

This only happens when targeting this specific server, this is the command I execute:

```
fab test --host remote-server
```

`remote-server` is an alias on my `.ssh/config`. My fabfile:

```
@task
def test():
    sudo("echo testing")
    put("/tmp/file.txt", "/tmp/")
```

`tmp/test_file.txt` is just a text file I'm using for my tests

This is the output

```
[remote-server] Executing task 'test'
[remote-server] sudo: echo testing
[remote-server] out: testing

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/fabric/main.py", line 712, in main
    *args, **kwargs
  File "/home/user/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/fabric/tasks.py", line 298, in execute
    multiprocessing
  File "/home/user/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/fabric/tasks.py", line 197, in _execute
    return task.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/fabric/tasks.py", line 112, in run
    return self.wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/project/fabfile/__init__.py", line 33, in test
    put("/tmp/file.txt", "/tmp/")
  File "/home/user/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/fabric/network.py", line 457, in host_prompting_wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/fabric/operations.py", line 338, in put
    ftp = SFTP(env.host_string)
  File "/home/user/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/fabric/sftp.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.ftp = connections[host_string].open_sftp()
  File "/home/user/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ssh/client.py", line 399, in open_sftp
    return self._transport.open_sftp_client()
  File "/home/user/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ssh/transport.py", line 844, in open_sftp_client
    return SFTPClient.from_transport(self)
  File "/home/user/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ssh/sftp_client.py", line 105, in from_transport
    chan.invoke_subsystem('sftp')
  File "/home/user/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ssh/channel.py", line 240, in invoke_subsystem
    self._wait_for_event()
  File "/home/user/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ssh/channel.py", line 1114, in _wait_for_event
    raise e
ssh.SSHException: Channel closed.
Disconnecting from root@server.com... done.
```

Is there anything I need to configure on the remote server to be able to send files using `put`?

Comment: Fabric makes use of SSH. For `put`, it might use `scp` or `sftp`. Try to use `scp` to upload a file manually first to make sure your environment works well with that.

Comment: `scp` works, `sftp` doesn't. I'll look for a way to enable `sftp` on the server. Thanks!

This is the output I get when trying to sftp to the server: `subsystem request failed on channel 0
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer`

Comment: @Drake: is there a way to make fabric use scp rather than sftp?

Comment: @LaszloPapp: For the current implementation in `fabric/operations.py` and `fabric/sftp.py`, there is no option for that. fabric uses the wrapped `SFTP` class for `put`. According to http://superuser.com/questions/134901/whats-the-difference-between-scp-and-sftp, it should be kind of hard to simulate sftp by scp though.

Comment: @Drake: I found a paramiko scp module though which calls the scp command explicitly, but I got sftp work yesterday instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to @Drake I found out that there was an issue with the `sftp` server on the remote machine.

To test for this:

```
$ sftp remote-server
subsystem request failed on channel 0
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer
```

I read that in order to enable `sftp` I needed to add the line

```
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and restart (`/etc/init.d/ssh restart`) the ssh service. But the line was already there and it wasn't working.

Then, after reading http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=42818, I changed that line for

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
```

restarted the `ssh` service, and it is now working:

```
$ sftp remote-server
Connected to remote-server
sftp>
```

Comment: I miss the explanation from your reply whether it is OK to change that file all the time when you upgrade or install the package on a machine. I mean, there must be a reason why that setting is not the default, and that is I think necessary to know for safely modifying the server config...

Comment: This did it for me. Only solution that solved the Channel Closed issue with Paramiko/Fabric. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue.
I found sftp was not installed on my server.
I installed openssh and restarted sshd service.

```
yum -y install openssh
service sshd restart
```

Then also i had same issue.
I checked the system log /var/log/messages. I found following error

```
Jul  3 04:23:20 <ip> sshd[13996]: subsystem request for sftp
Jul  3 04:23:20 <ip> sshd[13996]: error: subsystem: cannot stat /usr/libexec/sftp-   server: No such file or directory
Jul  3 04:23:20 <ip> sshd[13996]: subsystem request for sftp failed, subsystem not found
```

I locate my sftp-server location which was in "/usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server" and script was looking at "/usr/libexec/sftp-server" location
I created symbolic link and my issue got resolved.

```
root@<ip> fabric]# locate sftp-server
/usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
/usr/share/man/man8/sftp-server.8.gz

ln -s /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server /usr/libexec/sftp-server
```

Comment: ls -ld /usr/lib/sftp-server 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19 Oct 25 18:04 /usr/lib/sftp-server -> openssh/sftp-server => This is on my Ubuntu 12.04 by default, so I am not sure if this answer is useful these days. Could you please clarify?